# Ios release dates for developers

Tags: ios

Is there a way for developers with an ios enterprise agreement to find out about upcoming ios updates earlier than the public?

Answer (score 3):

Apple does not offer this information (exact release dates) to developers (enterprise or otherwise).

However, a standard part of the developer agreement provides access to pre-release iOS software. So, **any** developer, enterprise or otherwise, is afforded access to versions of the iOS software before it is released to the public.

Comment: Do developers need to request the pre releases or will apple send them automatically?

Comment: Theres no need to `request` anything, When Apple does a pre-release you will Receive an email about its availability.

Comment: Hi Andy, So when you say pre-release, do you mean the beta releases?